# Compute probability of union of n events from array

Tags: php, math, probability, probability-theory

I have a PHP array containing N probabilities (of N different events). So it looks like:

```
$events = [0.85, 1, 0, 0.15, 0.49, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.59, 0.93]
```

where each value in the array is the probability of an event. I need to compute the probability of the union of those events. That is, how do I compute the probability of at least one event happening ?

Comment: Because your second element in the array is 1, the probability of at least one event happening is also 1 (event #2 always happens)

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux thanks, the array is just an example array. In my real problem it may contain thousands of elements and most of the time there are no 1's)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To calculate the probability of at least one event occurring, you must calculate the probability of no events occurring, which is the product of (`1 - p[event]`) for each event and then subtract that from 1. You can do that with this code:

```
$events = [0.85, 1, 0, 0.15, 0.49, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.59, 0.93];
$prob = 1.0;
foreach ($events as $event) {
    $prob *= (1.0 - $event);
}
echo "probability of at least one event is " . (1 - $prob) . "\n";
```

Output:

```
probability of at least one event is 1
```

Note that since the probability of some of your events is 1 (i.e. they are certain to happen), the probability of at least one event occurring is also 1.